# How to increment the value without using elif?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the code in the following format.When i entered the age 21 then i should get -0.4.similarly when i entered the age 22 then i should get -0.3,and so on.But i do not want these much line of code.How can i improve this code.can anyone please suggest me

```
age=int(input("\nEnter the age :"))
a=[-0.4,-0.3,-0.2]

if age==21: 

     print("beta coefficient is ",a[0])

elif  age==22:

    print("beta coefficient is",a[1])

elif age==23:

    print("beta coefficient is ",a[2])
```

Comment: Read about [Mapping Types — dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-46)

Answer (score 4):

May be you can use `dictionary` instead and use key to get the corresponding value as following:

```
a={21:-0.4, 22:-0.3, 23:-0.2}

print("beta coefficient is ",a[age])
```

## Update:

If entered value or `key` does not exist in the dictionary, it will raise `KeyError`. In that case `.get` can be used with default value of `None` (*or other value*) to return when key is not found:

```
print("beta coefficient is ",a.get(age, None))
```

Comment: I wrote him a little function definition, didn't want to jump to ahead, even though this is fantastic, cheers

Comment: thank u for your reply.but when i enter age 21 i should get -0.4.similary when i enterd age 22 i should get -0.3,and so on...how?

Comment: May be you can simply try something like `print('{0:.2f}'.format(-0.4 + (age-21)/10.0))`without anything needed.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an efficient way.

`print("beta co-efficient is", a[age-21])`
It's hard coded that the first value is 21, and that they increment by one, but for your case it will work.

Comment: i think you have not understood , teclnol is expecting integer index on the array you have mentioned (your use shows it too) . in this particular case this will work. your case teclnol's answer is the best.  Otherwise you can use dictionaries like Student answer